# Marketing Cloud Page Landing Page Not Mobile Responsive

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Setting up a basic landing page with image blocks, the images render fine on desktop but are not resizing for mobile. They are zoomed in on the image and you have to rotate to landscape on mobile to get the correct sizing.

Is there an easy solution to this or do cloud pages not have built in mobile response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question could be closed due to being off-topic since it is more related to HTML+CSS without any connections to Salesforce (considering that point #1 from below will not help). It could not be considered as full solution, yet will navigate you in the right direction to find the answer:

1. Firstly, go to the Image Block Content tab and see if the "Scale to Fit" checkbox is selected, it allows your image to be responsive based on the screen resolution the recipient uses.

[image]

2. Then check CSS and its `@media` [queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to hardcode the image size based on the resolution ranges.
3. Lastly, you can set dynamic image size based on some other related assets, e.g. `<div>` tag. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container) for inspiration.